# Split an image with a zig-zag in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing, pathfinder

I've been trying for the last 3 nights to halve a simple vector image of a padlock I had drawn following a tutorial. My headache is: I don't want to simple divide it right at the middle, I want to divide it with a zig-zag.

This is the intended result:

[image: intended result]

My first idea was simple: using the pen tool, I drew freehand a zig-zag, gave it a stroke width, put it over the padlock and used the Pathfinder "Minus front". The problem was the path wasn't a real zig-zag, but Illustrator made it a string of triangles, so it didn't split it the way I wanted.

My second try was using a line, and the Zig-Zag effect. I used the minus front again, but the line simply disappears, without any visible effect on the padlock. I'm going nuts with this annoying software. I miss the age when we could simple use pen and paper to draw. :(

Please, how can I obtain the result above using this simple vector:

[image: my vector]

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your second method....

A simple straight vertical stroke with `Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig-Zag` applied.

Then choose `Object > Expand Appearance`, then `Object > Expand` to covert the zig zag stroke to a shape.

Then use Pathfinder.

[image]